# PostGis Scaling for Polygons at a fixed center location

Tags: postgis, polygon, scale, scale-factor

I need to enlarge/expand a 2D polygon at its fixed location (lat,lon) with a constant scale factor in order to retrieve the surrounding area with the same shape as the origin polygon.

What PostGIS function can I use and is this even possible to achieve?

Principally, I'm looking for a function similar to PostGISs [ST_Scale()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Scale.html), which only works for geometry data, which has no center.

Can you assist with the necessary transformations that come with this issue?

---

My Idea to solve the problem. I'm sure, that it can be formatted better:

```
SELECT 
st_astext(st_centroid(way)) as polygoncenter,
ST_AsText(way) as originalpolygon,
ST_AsText(
    ST_Translate(way, -ST_X(ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(way))), -ST_Y(ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(way))))
    ) as translatedtoorigin,
ST_AsText(  
    ST_SCALE(ST_Translate(way, -ST_X(ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(way))), -ST_Y(ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(way)))),2,2)
    ) as scaledatorigin,
ST_AsText(  
    ST_Translate(ST_SCALE(ST_Translate(way, -ST_X(ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(way))), -ST_Y(ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(way)))),2,2),ST_X(ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(way))), ST_Y(ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(way))))
    ) as scaledatoriginalposition
FROM de_polygon LIMIT 1000
```

The last parameter **scaledatoriginalposition** is the value I want to retrieve.
Isn't there any shorter way or given functionality by Postgis to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Due to some ideas from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61786/how-to-scale-reduce-my-polygon-without-changing-the-central-lat-long) I was able to figure it out.

But I was actually searching for the **ST_Buffer()** method, which is way much easier, than this complex query. Finally, I discovered that the results were different that I expected and **ST_Buffer()** totally meets my needs!

Result:

```
SELECT 
ST_Difference(
    ST_Buffer(area, ST_MaxDistance(area, area)/2),area) as surroundingarea
FROM (SELECT way as area FROM de_polygon WHERE boundary='administrative') as t
```

Maybe there is someone out there, who can use this :-)